# .htaccess and redirection - anything but this list redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

How do I say in an .htaccess file that I want to take anything that doesn't match:

main.php
index.php
/images/*
/css/*

and redirect it at the / of the current website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Anything else you need to turn on or enable to get this to work? Not working for me with just the .htaccess file and restarting server process

Comment: mod_rewrite is being loaded.

Comment: You may need to enable .htaccess files in the Apache config using [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: For .htaccess files you also need the FollowSymlinks option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule !(main.php|index.php|/images/|/css/) / [R]
```

You can "bookend" and of these with `^` and `$` if you want them to be more restrictive.

```
RewriteRule !(main.php$|^/index.php$|^/images/|^/css/) / [R]
```

You will probably want to add `^/$` into that list as well or you will end up with a redirect loop.

Comment: You need to include / in the list of items *not* to redirect or you'll get an infinite loop (which I discovered in testing my original answer).